# How to create dashed-border rectangle in plantuml

Tags: uml, graphviz, diagram, sequence-diagram, plantuml

To create a rectangle, I can simply `rectangle "Rectangle Label" as RectangleName`, but how to make its border dashed? like below?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJCiN.png]

Answer (score 15):

Add `#line.dashed` at the end of the statement:

```
rectangle "Rectangle Label" as RectangleName #line.dashed
```

### [Live Demo](http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/AqfDBadCIyz9LL0AWZ6L51AB5U0ylyJSL2uaPIw9nHcfARgegY62A7eKb7CoyrBrKi0o0000)

Answer (score 2):

```
@startuml
agent a
cloud c #pink;line:red;line.bold;text:red [
c
cloud description
]
file  f #palegreen;line:green;line.dashed;text:green {
[c1]
[c2]
}
frame frame {
node  n #aliceblue;line:blue;line.dotted;text:blue
}
@enduml
```

Reference > https://plantuml.com/deployment-diagram